# ¿Cómo crear y envolver componentes padre a hijo de un formulario?

Tags: reactjs

Estoy intentando crear mis primeros componentes aplicando la lógica de React(Crear bloques de lego para luego reutilizarlos) para un formulario, pero no entiendo como envolver el componente FormGET y FormGrup a mis otros elementos.
Estos componentes abren y cierran pero no entiendo como envolver estos componentes como Padres hacia los hijos
Ejemplo:

**Mi vista**

```
const RegisterView = function () {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="title">
          <h1>Registro</h1>
        </div>
        <FormGET>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label labelFor="Input_name" title="Nombre completo:" />
            <Input id="input_name" name="Name" type="text" value={EmployeeName} />
          </FormGroup>

          <FormGroup>
            <Label labelFor="input_email" title="Direccion de correo:" />
            <Input id="input_email" name="Email" type="email" value={EmployeeNameEmail} />
          </FormGroup>

          <FormGroup>
            <Label labelFor="input_age" title="Edad:" />
            <Input id="input_age" name="Age" type="number" value={EmployeeNameEmail} />
          </FormGroup>
        </FormGET>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default RegisterView;
```

**FormGET**

```
const FormGET = function () {
  return <form method="get">

  </form>;
};

export default FormGET;
```

**FormGroup**

```
const FormGroup = function () {
  return <div className="form-group">

  </div>;
};

export default FormGroup;
```

**Label**

```
const Label = function ({ labelFor,title}) {
  return <label htmlFor={labelFor}>{title}</label>;
};
export default Label;
```

**Input**

```
const Input = function ({ id, name,type, value }) {
  return <input id={id} name={name} type={type} value={value}/>;
};

export default Input;
```

Me estoy guiando de los componente de:
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/forms/overview/

No quiero usar esa libreria, lo que busco o quiero es *entender como trabaja React.*

Comment: Lo que pides es bastante extenso de explicar aqui. Pero si lo que quieres es aprender formularios de forma nativa en react te recomiendo este canal https://youtu.be/ECWR2ohHWKc ahi tienes lo basico pero tiene mas videos explicando cosas avanzadas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cada componente en React cuando tiene componentes hijos tiene acceso a una prop  llamada **children** la cual todo lo que se pase dentro de ese componente se tomara como children,
ejemplo:

```
    <Padre>
      <Hijo /> //ambos conforman children
      <Hijo/>  //ambos conforman children 
    </Padre>

   <Padre>
    {children}
   </Padre>
```

Por lo tanto tu código del componente padre quedaria asi:

```
const FormGET = function (props) { //podrias usar destructuring { children }
  return <form method="get">
     { props.children }
  </form>;
};

export default FormGET;
```

aqui **children** mostrara los hijos que en este caso son Los FormGroup (los cuales tienen sus propios hijos)

ahora FormGroup

```
const FormGroup = function (props) { //podrias usar destructuring { children
  return (
     <div className="form-group">
        { props.children } 
     </div>
  );
};

export default FormGroup;
```